# Python Sum excel file

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file that has 3 columns.
Please example below

```
Name      Produce     Number
Adam      oranges     6
bob       Apples      5
Adam      Apples      4
steve     Peppers     7
bob       Peppers     16
Adam      oranges     5
```

I need to generate the sum in python in such a way

```
Name      Produce     Number
Adam      oranges     11
bob       apples      5
steve     peppers     7
etc
```

I am new to python and trying to figure out how to write the output of each persons totals? is there an easy way to gather this data from excel?

Comment: This is quite easy if you know where in the Python library to look. Have you already managed to open the Excel file in Python?

Comment: yes I can open the file in excel, but do I have to open the excel file first, to be able to write it to python?

Comment: Wait can you reword: "to be able to write it to python?"

Comment: I need the total ( 2nd example above) generated in python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code for it:

Be sure to look at the comments and post back here if you have any questions (or if I made any mistakes)

```
import csv

file  = open('names.csv', "rb") #Open CSV File in Read Mode
reader = csv.reader(file)      #Create reader object which iterates over lines

class Object:                   #Object to store unique data
    def __init__(self, name, produce, amount):
        self.name = name
        self.produce = produce
        self.amount = amount

rownum = 0 #Row Number currently iterating over
list = []  #List to store objects

def checkList(name, produce, amount):

    for object in list:  #Iterate through list        
        if object.name == name and object.produce == produce:  #Check if name and produce combination exists
            object.amount += int(amount) #If it does add to amount variable and break out
            return

    newObject = Object(name, produce, int(amount)) #Create a new object with new name, produce, and amount
    list.append(newObject)  #Add to list and break out


for row in reader:  #Iterate through all the rows
    if rownum == 0:  #Store header row seperately to not get confused
        header = row
    else:
        name = row[0]  #Store name
        produce = row[1]  #Store produce
        amount = row[2]  #Store amount

        if len(list) == 0:  #Default case if list = 0
            newObject = Object(name, produce, int(amount))
            list.append(newObject)
        else:  #If not...
            checkList(name, produce, amount)


rownum += 1

for each in list: #Print out result
    print each.name, each.produce, each.amount

file.close() #Close file
```

Comment: I run it, and I am getting the output of just - - - Adam Oranges 5  It does look up the other names and sum up the total for Adam and oranges, I am trying to work through it..... let me see what I can get. Will be a chance to try to leran how to fix a problem, but any tips would be helpful :)

Comment: Yea i see a problem... one second im trying to fix it.... sorry i just send what I had without really testing it.

Comment: no problem. I am trying to see what I can get but just messing it up more. I am new and very very slow, but this helps alot of seeing how someone that knows what they are doing would set it up.

Comment: Take a look at it again. I fixed up the code. Also try making sure all the indentations are exactly like it is typed here.

Comment: ok got this ..... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/test", line 22, in <module>
    newObject = Object(name, produce, int(amount)) #Create a new object with new name, produce, and amount
NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, missed that indentation while copying the code to StackOverflow... look at my edits on the code again..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12471/discussion-between-tabchas-and-adam-g)

Comment: I actually got that one, but now I run it and get no errors but no data generated in python?

Comment: Click continue discussion in chat.

Answer (score 3):

Should be very straightforward once you have the Excel file open. 
If it is saved as a .csv file, use this documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Use this link to then iterate over the records and get the sum of each of the Name and Type: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/handling-csv-files-python

Comment: +1 for `csv` -- way easier to use than `xlrd` -- especially if you don't care about formatting

Comment: Yea usually people dont leave it in excel as you can easily save it as .csv.

Comment: how would I sum the number column together, I am having problem with that. I want all of lines with "bobs" "apples" to be a total sum of all lines that contain those two? Sorry probably really easy

Comment: Yea no problem... sorry i was busy ill do it now.

Answer (score 2):

1) Read Excel file with http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd

2) Iterate over the records, and use a composite key (Name, Produce) in dictionary ( [Object of custom type as dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901815/object-as-a-dictionary-key) ) to accumulate sum