# Python excel Sum lists

Tags: python, excel

I listed the follwoing question:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005335/python-sum-excel-file
```

I got great help on it, and now I am trying to convert another list in the same format and I am getting the following error using same code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/test2", line 37, in <module>
    checkList(name, symbol, amount)
  File "C:/Python27/test2", line 22, in checkList
    newObject = Object(name, symbol, int(amount)) #Create a new object with new name, produce, and amount
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I also was wondering if it is possible to convert the two excel files and then compare the two against each other to see differences?

Comment: clearly you are passing a bad string to int().  Just add a print of amount in your code before calling int().  Just before the error you'll see your non-int string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this error because at the line `newObject = Object(name, symbol, int(amount))`, the variable `amount` is an empty string.

There are two possibilities here, either that represents invalid data and you should not create a new `Object` instance to add to your list, or it is okay for `amount` to be `''` and you just want to give it a default value (probably `0`).  Here is one way to do this:

```
newObject = Object(name, produce, int(amount) if amount else 0)
```

Comment: how can you tell amount is empty, as opposed to an invalid string like 'abc'

Comment: @TJD - based on the error message: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`.

Comment: got it, didn't see that it was printing the literal ''