# User Defined Types as Dictionary Keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I've been struggling with the concept of hash tables and dictionaries for the last few days and couldn't find a proper solution to my problem. I hope you will forgive me for my beginner (and probably duplicated) question and spare the time to answer me.

During the initialization of my "World" (FSM as part of solving the classic GridWorld MDP problem, but this is not the issue here) I've created various instances of `State`, each of them has a unique and characterizing tuple `(row, column)`. My question is how can I store and refer to these instances.

### To be more specific...

I have created several states with the following code (using lists for storing them after failing several other alternatives, e.g. dictionaries, sets and NumPy arrays):

```
(rows, columns) = (3, 4)
s = [[] for _ in range(rows)]
for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(columns):
        s[r].append(State(r, c))
```

where the class is defined by:

```
class State:
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.row, self.col))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.row == other.row) & (self.col == other.col)

    # __hash__ and __eq__ are here because I know they should,
    # though I currently don't know how to use them.
    # I believe that is actually the real question here...
```

Later in my code I wish to assign to each state an attribute `neighbours`, which is a list of the **actual** states close to it on the grid. By "actual" I mean that they are not copies of the states or some representation of the states, but rather the states themselves. Below you can find my not-what-I-was-looking-for implementation:

```
def add_neighbours(self):
    if self.row == 0:
        if self.col == 0:
            self.neighbours = [(0, 1), (1, 0)]
        elif self.col == 1:
            self.neighbours = [(0, 0), (0, 2)]
        elif self.col == 2:
            self.neighbours = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 3)]
        elif self.col == 3:
            self.neighbours = [(0, 2), (1, 3)]
    elif self.row == 1:
        if self.col == 0:
            self.neighbours = [(0, 0), (2, 0)]
        elif self.col == 1:
            self.neighbours = []  # Pit, N/A
        elif self.col == 2:
            self.neighbours = [(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2)]
        elif self.col == 3:
            self.neighbours = [(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
    elif self.row == 2:
        if self.col == 0:
            self.neighbours = [(1, 0), (2, 1)]
        elif self.col == 1:
            self.neighbours = [(2, 0), (2, 2)]
        elif self.col == 2:
            self.neighbours = [(2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
        elif self.col == 3:
            self.neighbours = [(2, 2), (1, 3)]
```

This definition of `neighbours` allows me to call the relevant states from `s`, but it is not a pretty sight and surly not elegant. What I look for is something of the sort:

```
def add_neighbours(self):
    if self.row == 0:
        if self.col == 0:
            self.neighbours = [State((0, 1)), State((1, 0))]
        elif self.col == 1:
            self.neighbours = [State((0, 0)), State((0, 2))]
        elif self.col == 2:
            self.neighbours = [State((0, 1)), State((1, 2)), State((0, 3))]
etc...
```

where `State((r, c))` is the **actual** state (or I should say reference to state) called again and again.

Any comment will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Note: I am aware of detailed attempts for explanations (e.g. [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901815/object-as-a-dictionary-key) and [this Python Wiki reference](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys), but unfortunately I failed to work them out and had to ask for more explanations.

Comment: Originally I thought I should use it, but I didn't know how, so after several attempts I've dismissed it. This is basically the reason I'm asking the question...

Comment: The question is not clear. What is an MDP? What does an State means? What are you trying to acheive? Are you translating the code from other programming language? Do you know any other programming language? This sounds like a graph, but Im not sure.

Comment: I tried to be as clear as I could. The background of MDP is irrelevant here, and "state" (in this context) is a location on the grid. If more convenient, you may think of "students" instead of "states", sitting in a class of size 3x4. The question will remain the same.

Comment: So you have a matrix and for each cell you explicitly list each neighbor. Right?

Comment: Right. And I wish this list to contain the **actual** neighbours.

Comment: Well, that was my initial guess but it was not clear. So we have a graph! Lets build one :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but please note that the main concern is not `neighbours` and its architecture, but rather the reference to the class instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a planar graph and where each node can be positioned and indexed with a matrix.

What you can do is:

1. Create a backing indexing structure to store each individual cell, so you can reference a cell by its coordinates.
2. Create each empty individual cell and store in the backing indexing structure.
3. Once each empty cell was created, link each cell to its neighbors.

You need to first create each State empty, because you can't reference an object which was not yet created.

In code:

```
# 1. Backing index
table = {}

# 2. Each State is empty.
table[(0, 0)] = State(0, 0)
table[(0, 1)] = State(0, 1)
table[(1, 0)] = State(1, 0)
table[(1, 1)] = State(1, 1)
# ...

# 3. Initialize each State.
table[(0, 0)].initialize()
table[(0, 1)].initialize()
# ...

class State:
  def initialize(self):
    if ...:
      # self.neighbours is a list of States.
      self.neighbours = [table[(x, y)], table[(a, b)], table[(p, q)]]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working. However, I am still curious about the necessity of `__hash__` and `__eq__`, and would really like to see a good example of them at work. (BTW - I can't vote you up because it requires at least 15 reputations...)

Comment: @user3121900 You only need to make an object hashable is you are using that object as key. That's it, you already have an instance of that object and you want to get some other piece of information. This is not the case, since the object you want to get the instance of is the State object. Here we are using a plain tuple of coordinates to get the State instance.