# After being inserted as dict keys, some objects don't show up in the keys list

Tags: python, object, dictionary, hash

## Problem description

I want to used an object as a key in a dictionary. The attributes of the dictionary that I want to use to compare the keys are:  `DDATE, WEEK_PERIOD, DPERIOD, RPERIOD, ALLIANCE, DTIME, RTIME`. I want exclude the attributes `DCXR, RCXR, DCNX, RCNX`.

The output of the algorithm should be:

> AC, DL, SN, AF, LH

**The problem** is that as output it is only producing:

> AC AF

The other values are totally **lost**. However When I add  `DCXR, RCXR, DCNX, RCNX` to the **hash** and **eq** I get the right output. But I don't want THAT!! I don't want to use them when I insert keys in the dictionary.

I don't understand why it is excluding the other values in the output. From what I know I don't have to use all the attributed when I use the object as a Key in a dictionary.

The following source code produces exactly the error.

---

## Source code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import argparse

from collections import defaultdict

from functools import partial

class Key(object):
    def __init__(self, DDATE, WEEK_PERIOD, DPERIOD, RPERIOD, ALLIANCE, DTIME, RTIME, DCXR, RCXR, DCNX, RCNX):
            self.DDATE       = DDATE
            self.WEEK_PERIOD = WEEK_PERIOD
            self.DPERIOD     = DPERIOD
            self.RPERIOD     = RPERIOD
            self.ALLIANCE    = ALLIANCE
            self.DTIME = DTIME
            self.RTIME = RTIME
            self.DCXR = DCXR
            self.RCXR = RCXR
            self.DCNX = DCNX
            self.RCNX = RCNX
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.DDATE, self.WEEK_PERIOD, self.DPERIOD, self.RPERIOD, self.ALLIANCE,
                     self.DTIME, self.RTIME))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.DDATE, self.WEEK_PERIOD, self.DPERIOD, self.RPERIOD, self.ALLIANCE, 
        self.DTIME, self.RTIME) == (other.DDATE, other.WEEK_PERIOD, other.DPERIOD, other.RPERIOD, other.ALLIANCE, other.DTIME, other.RTIME)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not(self == other)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    dict = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, list)) 
    
    key = Key("01/15/17","2","1","2","0","13:50","18:25","AF","AF","CDG","YUL")
    dict[key][28].append(10.0)
        
    key = Key("01/15/17","2","1","2","0","13:05","20:10","AC","AC","CDG","YUL")
    dict[key][28].append(20.0)
        
    key = Key("01/15/17","2","1","2","0","13:50","18:25","DL","DL","CDG","YUL")
    dict[key][28].append(30.0)
        
    key = Key("01/15/17","2","1","2","0","13:05","20:10","SN","SN","CDG","YUL")
    dict[key][28].append(40.0)
        
    key = Key("01/15/17","2","1","2","0","13:05","20:10","LH","LH","CDG","YUL")
    dict[key][28].append(50.0)
    
    for key in dict.keys():
        print key.DCXR
```

Comment: I didn't, but it could be because they found your question unclear. I'm still trying to understand what you mean. Could you make your question clearer?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I insert 5 keys in a dictionary. and I end up with 2 keys only. I don't understand why. The output should be **AC, DL, SN, AF, LH** but I only get **AC AF**. I really don't understand why?? I also used the data to reproduce the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those objects don't vanish, they are just never inserted into the `dict` as keys. You say that you don't want to include `DCXR, RCXR, DCNX, RCNX` in the computation of the hash. That's fine. But you *should* include them in the `__eq__` check. Otherwise objects that differ in those attributes only are considered equal. This is exactly the case for your example:

- The 1st and 3rd only differ in those attributes.
- The 2nd, 4th and 5th also only differ in those attributes.

So what happens is that the 1st and 2nd objects are inserted as keys and for each subsequent `dict[key]` the old value is just overwritten because the keys compare equal.

---

**Side note:** You shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name because it shadows the built-in type `dict`.

Comment: A_guest thank you so  much. can I show you this link pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901815/object-of-custom-type-as-dictionary-key  In the following link they don't use length in the equal. I followed what they did. This is what confused me

Comment: @HaniGotc You have correctly implemented the two methods `__hash__` and `__eq__` however both do not include the attributes `DCXR, RCXR, DCNX, RCNX`. Therefore `Key("01/15/17","2","1","2","0","13:50","18:25","AF","AF","CDG","YUL")` and `Key("01/15/17","2","1","2","0","13:50","18:25","DL","DL","CDG","YUL")` compare equal and are considered the very same key (which leads to an update of the associated value). A dictionary is basically a hash map with linked lists as target objects. It uses the `__eq__` check to determine whether a key is already part of the corresponding list.

Comment: thank you @a_guest. I thought that something was wrong the program. you really helped. I understand