# How do I retrieve values given a key (thats of type PosixPath) in a python dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary `some_dict` with key (of type `PosixPath`) and value (of type `tensor`) that looks something like this:

```
{PosixPath('dataset_small/test/1db4b7f3f65739960cb553b8778982e7e6129e0d.tif'): tensor(0.0053),
PosixPath('dataset_small/test/b1762960a3b92ecc055ce06897378f42bf337c82.tif'): tensor(0.0498),
PosixPath('dataset_small/test/61416795264535918f705f2c93bfd532d23ee8da.tif'): tensor(0.0223),
...
```

How do I index through this dictionary?

I've tried `some_dict['dataset_small/test/' + id + '.tif']` but got the following error:

````
KeyError                                  
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-d7a2e0e6db0f> in <module>()
----> 1 pred_list_cor = [pred_dict['dataset_small/test/' + id + '.tif'] for id in sample_list]

<ipython-input-69-d7a2e0e6db0f> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 pred_list_cor = [pred_dict['dataset_small/test/' + id + '.tif'] for id in sample_list]

KeyError: 'dataset_small/test/0b2ea2a822ad23fdb1b5dd26653da899fbd2c0d5.tif'```.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question and I never tried before. I was trying to access the key directly as the previous answer advised using : value = some_dict[key] , but doesn't work for me and I found that you need to define 2 methods in your class to make it work : **hash** and **eq** Thanks to this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4901847/1855988

"
An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a **hash**() method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an **eq**() method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
"
https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable

**UPDATE**: I just notice that PosixPath is a predefined module. I thought it is a new class that you created :). I guess the answer is still useful!

**Code** :

```
class PosixPath:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.text))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.text) == (other.text)

class tensor:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value    

dic = {PosixPath('dataset_small/test/1db4b7f3f65739960cb553b8778982e7e6129e0d.tif'): tensor(0.0053)}


search = "dataset_small/test/1db4b7f3f65739960cb553b8778982e7e6129e0d.tif"
new = PosixPath(search)

dic[new].value
```

**Result** :

```
0.0053
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert string to `PosixPath` before you use it as key

```
key = PosixPath("dataset_small/test/0b2ea2a822ad23fdb1b5dd26653da899fbd2c0d5.tif")

value = some_dict[key]
```

---

```
pred_list_cor = [pred_dict[PosixPath('dataset_small/test/' + id + '.tif')] for id in sample_list]
```

---

Example code for test

```
from pathlib import PosixPath

data = {
    PosixPath('dataset_small/test/1db4b7f3f65739960cb553b8778982e7e6129e0d.tif'): 0.0053,
    PosixPath('dataset_small/test/b1762960a3b92ecc055ce06897378f42bf337c82.tif'): 0.0498,
    PosixPath('dataset_small/test/61416795264535918f705f2c93bfd532d23ee8da.tif'): 0.0223
}

print( data[PosixPath('dataset_small/test/61416795264535918f705f2c93bfd532d23ee8da.tif')] )
# 0.0223
```